# How to setup fields for retrieval from data extensions?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, python

I am trying to collect data from my data extension in exacttarget but am running into issues actually seeing and manipulating the data.

here is my code, that I got from here (https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/fuel-sdks/data-extensions/data-extension-retrieve.html#pythonpost). The 'aaaa' and '1111' are the name of the data extension I want to pull and clientID which is the external key found in the above link:

```
import ET_Client
myClient = ET_Client.ET_Client()
dataextension = ET_Client.ET_DataExtension()
dataextension.auth_stub = myClient
dataextension.props = ['aaaa', '1111']
dataextension.search_filter = {'StateProvCd' : 'CO'}
results = dataextension.get()
print results
```

This is the output I am getting:

```
<FuelSDK.rest.ET_Get object at 0x0000000036921F28>
```

When I dig deeper using result.message I get the following error:

```
"Report_Chase_AmFamconnect_Bounce,1111(external key) do not match with the fields of DataExtension retrieve"
```

but as you can see above i have included the fields above in 'StateProvCd' and the state name in that field.

Could anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the filter, it appears you are attempting to get data out of a data extension, not meta data about a data extension.  If this is the case then you would need to use the ET_DataExtension_Row instead of ET_DataExtension, details on that here:

https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/fuel-sdks/data-extension-rows/data-extension-row-retrieve.html#pythonpost

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me @Mac. You are correct I want the actual data in the data extension and not the metadata of the dataextension. I tried your suggestion and it has definitely gotten me closer to my solution but now when I dig deeper using 'results.message' the message says 'MoreDataAvailable' but still same message as above. '<FuelSDK.rest.ET_Get object at 0x0000000036921F28>'

If possible could you tell me how to access this data from 'MoreDataAvailable'?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Sorry for the second comment but I got the data out of results using 'results.results' but in the dataextension_Row example where does one specify the external key? I ask bc I want to confirm I pulling data from correct location

Comment: Please ignore I figured it out, your answer above was what I was looking for! thank you once again